# AWS Ubuntu: Configure Ejabberd Hosts from Snap Store

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, xmpp, ejabberd

I installed Ejabberd from Snap Store on Ubuntu, on an AWS EC2. I can access admin webpage "localhost:5280/admin" locally on Ubuntu. However, I cannot access it outside VNC from "https://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5280/admin". I guess I need to add "ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com" into hosts in ejabberd.yml according to some tutorials. But it is quite different for Ejabberd installed from Snap, as I see there are two ejabberd.xml, not sure which one I shall change.

```
root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:/home/ubuntu# ls /snap/ejabberd/37/config/
config.exs  ejabberd.exs  ejabberd.yml
root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:/home/ubuntu# ls /snap/ejabberd/current/config/
config.exs  ejabberd.exs  ejabberd.yml
root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:/home/ubuntu#
```

When I open file ejabberd.yml, I find it is readonly with an "equal mark" as picture shown. I am not sure whether I shall use chmod to modify read-write? Or there are other ways to add my aws ip-address to the hosts in config?

Comment: The correct path should be: /var/snap/ejabberd/37/etc/ejabberd.yml

Comment: However, I cannot access it outside VNC from... <-- why not? Does ejabberd receive that query and rejects it? Do you see that connection attempt in ejabberd log files?

Comment: @Badlop I found missing to config host_config. After I config it, I can access it through http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct yaml file for Ejabberd from Snap Store is /var/snap/ejabberd/37/etc/ejabberd.yml or /var/snap/ejabberd/current/etc/ejabberd.yml, which are the same file. And /snap/ejabberd/37/config/ is pointing to the above files